# How to read a local properties file from an executable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I developed and tested my program on Eclipse Indigo.  No problem finding the properties file when run.
I created a runnable jar using Eclipse export.
The program cannot find the properties file when the program is run from the jar.
The properties file is not in the jar, it is in a subdirectory of the directory where the jar is deployed.
As noted above, this directory is on the classpath in the Eclipse run configuration.

> C:/myApp/myApp.jar  C:/myApp/properties/myApp.properties

```
props.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myApp.properties"));
```

Do I just need to edit the Jar manifest to put the config directory on the classpath?

Comment: Why not use normal file I/O? If you don't want to hard code the location, then you can pass it as jvm parameter with `-D` or just calculate it from your actual location.

Answer (score 0):

```
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(configFileSrc));
```

This should work.

In my case, configFileSrc = "/apiconfig/appconfig.properties"

[image]

I had to add **staticresources** dir in the build path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Make sure you specify the path of the config directory relative to the directory where the jar is located. Since you said above that the config directory is a sub directory of the jar location, this will probably just be

```
<configDir>
```

where `<configDir>` is your configuration directory name.

You will also need to use an absolute resource name for the lookup, by adding a slash to the properties file name:

```
props.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/myApp.properties"));
```

This is because the relative name your specify will have the package path of the class appended to it, which you don't want.

Is there any specific reason you need to use the contextClassLoader? A simpler invocation would be to use the classLoader of the class containing the lookup. And, since the class can delegate to it's classLoader, you can simply say:

```
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myApp.properties"));
```

Finally - have you considered putting the properties file in the jar itself? If it's not going to change at all, this would be a better option. You wouldn't need to specify the classPath in that case. Note that if you want, you could put it in a sub-directory *in the jar* , but you would have to change the resource path you looked for, and again use an absolute resource name

Here is some info on absolute and relative resource names:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that you need to make up your mind where your application is going to load the properties from *when the application is deployed*.

(How it works in Eclipse is kind of irrelevant ... unless you expect your users to install Eclipse to run your app!)

- If you want it to load the properties from the JAR file, they need to be in the JAR file.
- If you want it to load the properties from the file system, they need to be in the file system.  That means you have two subsidiary issues:

  1. Where in the file system will your application look?  Bear in mind that this has to work for **all** of the OS platforms you support, and that different OSes have different conventions for where "configuration settings* should be stored.
  2. Is there a *default* version of the properties file, and how will you install it?
- If you want to load it from the CLASSPATH and not the JAR file, that means you cannot make your application an *executable JAR*.  (Running as `java -jar ...` will **ignore** all attempts to set an external classpath.)
- If you opt for a non-executable JAR file AND loading the properties from the classpath, you have more problems:

  1. How do you set the classpath?
  2. How do you install the properties file "alongside" the JAR file?
  3. Are there security concerns with a (potentially) user writable directory on the application's classpath?

  This is probably the worst option.

---

Once you have decided how (from where) your application needs to load its properties when deployed, the code for implementing your scheme is relatively straightforward.  (Modulo the problems mentioned above.)

You could even combine a couple of options; e.g. look for the properties file in the file system and then fall back to a "default" properties file in the JAR file.  Or you could make the file system location of the properties file a command line option or supply it via an environment variable or via `-D` and the system properties.